# Bad Request (400) response from Cowboy server, when hosting on heroku

Tags: asp.net-core, heroku, bad-request, cowboy

I have an app running on heroku and noticed today, that a particular request leads to a 400 response on Firefox but it works on Chrome. I also found out that if I remove an unnecessary cookie that requests succeeds again.

While investigating I also found an issue with chrome, where it wasn't able to fetch the CSS file, while loading the website:

[image]

However, opening that link in a new tab, I managed to load the CSS without any problems. Also removing that one extra cookie managed to sort it out.

All these 400 responses have one thing in common, they are served by the server "Cowboy"

[image]

The application I'm running is asp.net core, so it should return "Kestrel" as the server instead, but it seems that the request doesn't even get to the heroku router, because I can't even find them in the logs of the dyno.

I've tried to search online for an explanation and it seems that in case I'd be running against some limits, this is the response I should be expecting, but this is just a staging application and it works in chrome but doesn't work in firefox, so it's hard for me to imagine which limits I could be running against.

---

**Update:**

We've removed those unnecessary cookies, and now chrome loading the CSS seems to work fine, but Firefox is still getting a 400 Bad Request from the Cowboy server. Any ideas? I've only found [Why do I get a "400 Bad Request" response when I have large cookies?](https://help.heroku.com/TQ80D553/why-do-i-get-a-400-bad-request-response-when-i-have-large-cookies)
 - which doesn't seem to apply to me, the cookies are less than 4k and all browsers should have the same cookies, there is nothing on the server to differentiate between browsers.

Comment: Might be a CORS problem.

Comment: No, those are direct requests, not AJAX